# After SonarQube 5.2 upgrade java analysis fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There's no changeset on line

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

This is an analysis that I have been running for a while.
The SCM is Git.

I upgraded [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) to 5.2 (from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb as I am using Ubuntu LTS 14.04.3)

`sonar.log` now gives:

```
2015.11.17 10:43:00 ERROR web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=energy:energy | id=AVEVClvzTc_W2Q8I5ipV | time=647ms
```

Through the web interface I tracked down:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/ce/logs?taskId=AVEVClvzTc_W2Q8I5ipV
```

which gave:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There's no changeset on line 170
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ScmInfoImpl.getChangesetForLine(ScmInfoImpl.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ReportScmInfo.getChangesetForLine(ReportScmInfo.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.NewCoverageMeasuresStep$NewCoverageCounter.initialize(NewCoverageMeasuresStep.java:391) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
```

(It would be an improvement if the error message told you the file name in which it thinks line 170 is wrong.)

Is there anything to be done other than wait for version 5.3 ?

Comment: Hi, are you using sonar.scm.disabled=false ? If yes, you're encountering this ticket : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6897

Comment: No, I am using the default maven plugin (2.6) configuration, ie no configuration.

Comment: Upgrading maven plugin to 2.7.1 did not fix.

Comment: I changed all line ends to Unix, to no effect:`find * -type f -name '*.java'  -exec dos2unix '{}' \;`

Comment: Could you give me the list of installed plugins ?

Comment: Cobertura Additional Metrics 1.6.3, 
Generic Coverage Additional Metrics 1.1, 
Git Integration 1.1, 
JIRA Integration 1.2 , 
Java Languages 3.7.1.  So I am guessing it will be the Cobertura plugin. Move to Jacoco ?

Comment: Indeed, it could be interesting to generate the coverage with Jacoco and check if it's working better.

Comment: Did you remove `sonar/data/es directory` during upgrade?

Comment: I have now deleted the data/es directory but the same problem exists. I upgraded 'by accident' in that I am running Ubuntu and just did an `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I removed the Cobertura plugin and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for the Java plugin. I solved it by executing an analysis with SCM support disabled:

```
sonar.scm.disabled = true
```

Note that **I didn't have to disable it permanently,** only for **one analysis**. After that it worked fine again.

Comment: I tried with the SCM disabled and then back to enabled and the problem didn't go away. Nice that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but the problem turned out to be the javascript plugin. I was running the latest version (2.8) installed through the update centre. After removing the plugin, the analysis succeeded but now I have no metrics on the Javascript code, which is roughly have the project code base.

Incidentally, the maven sonar plugin (2.7.1) reports "ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL" even though the analysis actually failed.

EDIT: I noticed a new version (2.9) of the Javascript plugin. Analysis succeeded after the upgrade.