# SonarQube 5.2 - JoCoCo code coverage analysis failing

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube5.2

Trying to add JoCoCo code coverage results to SonarQube. Sonar runner succeeds but SonarQube background task is failing with following, what could be wrong?

```
2016.01.25 15:45:49 INFO  [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Execute task | project=some-app | id=AVJ5dmm7k4BvzpgpsUo9
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExtractReportStep] Analysis report extracted | compressedSize=2 MB
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Extract report | time=308ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep] SonarQube plugins:
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - GitHub 1.1 (github)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - CSS 1.6 (css)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Findbugs 3.3 (findbugs)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Java 3.8 (java)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - LDAP 1.5.1 (ldap)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Git 1.1 (scmgit)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Android 1.1 (android)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - PHP 2.7 (php)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Widget Lab 1.8.1 (widgetlab)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - SVN 1.2 (scmsvn)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - JavaScript 2.10 (javascript)
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep] Settings for module: CUT
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.binaries=some/path
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.id=20160125154322
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.startTime=2016-01-25T15:43:22+0000
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.version=5.2
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.host.url=http://192.168.45.100:9000
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.jacoco.reportPath=testDebugUnitTest-2.exec
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.libraries=
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.permission.template.default=default_template
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/paat/git/some-app
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectKey=some-app
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectName=Some App
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectVersion=1.0
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.qualitygate=1
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.sources=some/src
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.working.directory=/Users/paat/git/some-app/.sonar
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Log scanner context | time=2ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Build tree of components | time=61ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Validate project | time=6ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load debt model | time=4ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load quality profiles | time=120ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load Quality gate | time=5ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load differential periods | time=12ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute size measures | time=98ms
2016.01.25 15:45:50 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Failed to execute task AVJ5dmm7k4BvzpgpsUo9
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There's no changeset on line 14
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ScmInfoImpl.getChangesetForLine(ScmInfoImpl.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ReportScmInfo.getChangesetForLine(ReportScmInfo.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.NewCoverageMeasuresStep$NewCoverageCounter.initialize(NewCoverageMeasuresStep.java:391) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.processLeaf(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:165) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.process(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:142) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.formula.FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.visitFile(FormulaExecutorComponentVisitor.java:122) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:89) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:57) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.NewCoverageMeasuresStep.execute(NewCoverageMeasuresStep.java:113) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:78) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.run(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:55) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
2016.01.25 15:45:50 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=some-app | id=AVJ5dmm7k4BvzpgpsUo9 | time=1010ms
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755226/after-sonarqube-5-2-upgrade-java-analysis-fails-with-java-lang-illegalargumentex

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is coverage information for lines of code that no longer exist. This information was generated in past analyzes. To remove them, be sure to run a `clean` initially.